# How can I convert these 'if' statements to an algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to convert these 'if' statements to an algorithm, so that I can have many more stages instead of being limited to 10. How would I go about converting it? I just can't wrap my head around the logic!

```js
function getStage(km) { 
    if (km > 2 && km < 4){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (km > 4 && km < 6){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (km > 6 && km < 8){
        return 3;
    }
    else if (km > 8 && km < 10){
        return 4;
    }
    else if (km > 10 && km < 12){
        return 5;
    }
    else if (km > 12 && km < 14){
        return 6;
    }
    else if (km > 14 && km < 16){
        return 7;
    }
    else if (km > 16 && km < 18){
        return 8;
    }
    else if (km > 18 && km < 20){
        return 9;
    }
    else if (km > 20 && km < 22){
        return 10;
    }
}
```

I have tried this:

```js
function getStage(km) { 
    var tempStage = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < stages; i++) {
        var stage = i + 1;
        var tempKm = stage * 2;
        var nextKm = stage + 2;

        if (km > tempKm && km < nextKm) {
            tempStage = stage;
        }
    }
    return tempStage;
}
```

Perhaps I shouldn't be using a for loop? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: what about a value like `4`. what to return in this case?

Comment: `if (km > 2 && km < 4)` that seems like a roundabout way of writing `if(km == 3)`

Comment: Stage 2 because it is less than 6

Comment: You have a huge number of unhandled cases. If you can describe correctly what the function should return for each input, we can help.

Comment: @RichardJacobs not according to these statements `4 > 4` is false, so it will not return anything.

Comment: do you have a max value?

Comment: So i have an app that converts the number of kilometres into stages. So if you have walked 4.67 km you are at stage 2.

Comment: Try _return Math.floor(km/2);_

Comment: But if you've walked `3.99` kilometers, you are at stage 1, at `4` you are at no stage at all until you take another step and get into stage 2

Comment: Its always divisible by 2, that's all there is to it...

Comment: I knew it. Apology for being so stupid haha :-)

Comment: what if your stages are *not* always `2*n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for Math.floor

```js
function getStage(km) {
    return Math.floor(km / 2)
}
console.log(getStage(2));
// 1
console.log(getStage(10));
// 5
console.log(getStage(11));
// 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use math to do this. No loops or conditionals necessary.

Notice that your input intervals increase in "steps" of 2, and your outputs increase in "steps" of 1. This makes me think maybe we should **divide km by 2**.
Since we always want an integer answer, we can use the `Math.floor` function.

Some examples:

```
Math.floor(3/2) = 1  
Math.floor(4.1/2) = 2
```

etc.

Depending on what you want to return for edge cases (what if km = 2 or km = 4, or any multiple of 2?) we might be done here. If you wish to return 1 when k=4, 2 when k=6, etc., you'll need to do a little more work.

*** In general: *** if you are working with numbers and you find yourself writing a lot of cases, you can usually use some combination of simple mathematical operators to calculate the result. For problems like these, try thinking about your input/output pairs, and what the relationship is between them.

Answer (score 1):

You could take the floored value of `km` divided by two plus one.

`10` is the upper limit.

```js
function getStage(km) {
    return Math.min((km >> 1) + 1, 10);
}

console.log(getStage(2.1)); // 2
console.log(getStage(3)); // 2
console.log(getStage(4)); // 4
```

Comment: `>> 1` is really obscure. I think you should write `floor(km / 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. This is general solution which applies not only to `2*n` series.

```js
const stages = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 13, 15, 16, 20]; //should be ordered. Else sort it first.

const getStage = km => stages.indexOf(stages.find(i => km < i));

console.log(getStage(5)); //2
console.log(getStage(1.5)); //0
console.log(getStage(8.1)); //4
console.log(getStage(15)); //7
console.log(getStage(22)); //-1 out of index
```